# PHP save filled PDF to server from iframe

Tags: php, pdf

I am developing a PHP employee application section for a client's secure website. They want the potential employee to fill out a W4 fillable PDF and have it emailed to them. I have found some solutions for pulling information from a PHP form and spitting it out to the PDF via PDFTK.

What I am curious about is: Can I achieve the same result by having the user fill out the actual PDF form (maybe in iframe or however) via PHP? or am i stuck developing the W4 in PHP then transferring the submitted values to PDFTK?

I'm just thoroughly confused on this whole process, so any insight or resources are appreciated.

Comment: do you mean create pdf forms dynamically? Yes, you can it with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you really want is for the PDF document to post itself to a url.  That way you can let people view/use the pdf, and receive/save the whole document when they are done.  This will probably make your client happy, since they likely have a whole workflow based on those W4 PDFs.  See [Can a PDF fillable form post itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631008/can-a-pdf-fillable-form-post-itself-to-an-https-url).

Comment: that actually sounds like a great approach! and thank you for the link!