# Is there anyway to save an interactive pdf using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

We display a pdf to user, which has blank fields to be filled. Right now, user has to fill the pdf, save a copy on his/her machine and then upload it back to our website, for us to save it in our database.

But is there anyway to save the filled pdf directly to our datasbe, without saving on user's machine?

Comment: You would still need some way to get the details from the user to insert into the PDF in that case.

Comment: You could try to make PDF form that submits data to your app URL. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631008/can-a-pdf-fillable-form-post-itself-to-an-https-url

Comment: Konstantin...It helped to some extent...but I am still not able to completely implement it...anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is also a pdf standard (FDF) that was designed specifically for this. Upon filling a form in this kind of pdf, the data gets sent to the server automagically.

There's a sample for creating this kind of document on the iText website.
Check out

- http://itextpdf.com/tags/fdf
- http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-edit-pdf-embedded-browser-and-save-pdf-directly-server