# PDF Filling and saving in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, frameworks

i have 5 PDF's that are editable, if i open it on the website, i can still write on it. What i wanted to know is, after the user fills the pdf, how can i make it save what the user filled and "update" the pdf to save it on the database?
Is there something that does it?
Am i suposed to open the pdf it self in the browser? or a page that includes the pdf as a frame or something

I've already researched a bit but i only find building the form into a PDF, i wanna edit the pdf and save the pdf. It goes in blank and then the user saves it with all the information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631008/can-a-pdf-fillable-form-post-itself-to-an-https-url here is a very similar problem. But you need to edit the 5 pdf files

Comment: That's a really nice method, thanks. But i wanted to save the pdf as a file, i dont want to upload it to a different url, but upload it to my database filled up with the information the user filled in. And i dont have space in my pdf to put in the button so thats a big problem aswell >.>
Basicly image a page, in which you  have a pdf in the middle for you to fill up, then you have a button OUTSIDE the pdf, in which saves the form and uploads it to the database.

Edit: Maybe, better to generate a different PDF with the filled in info so that the empty pdf stays as a template, right?

Comment: i think the solution you want is not possible. At least not easy without "hacks". If you don't save the pdf-file with the new input, php can't get the new information out of it. Maybe with a lot of javascript you can captcha the input from the user... maybe ;)

Comment: oooh.... ok thank you. But can i make the pdf button save my pdf? instead of redirecting to a url???

Comment: your post button will upload the edited form data, the server side could build a new pdf that contains the filled form, and save that

Comment: or you can let the user download the pdf, he fill in the data and upload it on your server....